# How do you abort the current recipe during the Chef compile phase?

Tags: chef-infra

Under some conditions, you want to abort the current recipe during the Chef compile phase? What is the recommended way to accomplish this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to abort the current recipe during the Chef compile phase is to return.

Note, this will not abort a Chef run. For how to abort a Chef run, see [How to Abort/End A Chef Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290397/how-do-you-abort-end-a-chef-run).

The response from [jtimberman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7672/jtimberman) to [How to Abort/End A Chef Run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294011/179332) gives an incredible amount of background on this topic and is highly recommened.