# How can I get chef to reboot the node, and pick up the recipe from where it left off?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, cookbook, berkshelf

I'm trying to set up an asterisk server with chef using Berkshelf and Vagrant, and I'd first like to upgrade the kernel by running

> apt-get upgrade

, and rebooting my machine.

How can I trigger a reboot in the recipe, and have it pick up after the machine reboots? I have no problem with this using Fabric, but

> execute "reboot"

the Chef provisioner in Vagrant died as the machine rebooted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) is one of the principles of Chef.

This means that your recipe can run over and over again, and it will only change things that are not as expected.

So in your case it would look like this:

- First Chef run notices that an unexpected kernel is installed. It thus installs the kernel and triggers a reboot.
- Chef runs again, identifies that the kernel is installed as expected and thus just continues. Now you can continue with other things.

One note: I've never tried this, but signalling a `reboot` in the middle of a Chef run could do some damage. I'd recommend to abort the chef run after the `reboot` signal (e.g. through raising an Exception, see [How do you abort/end a Chef run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290397/how-do-you-abort-end-a-chef-run)).

Comment: Ah, just read that you even prote that "Chef provisioner in Vagrant died as the machine rebooted". With vagrant it's a bit special, as it doesn't run chef again on reboot. But for servers not running Vagrant, it should work out. With Vagrant, you have to issue a `vagrant reload` yourself.