# Chef powershell_script guard throws false when throwing an exception

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef powershell_script which seems to be running whenever the not_if guard throws an exception, I would like to change it so that the chef run fails when the not_if throws an exception, would that be possible?

Here's some really simplistic code, at the moment it seems to create the file, even though the guard is throwing an exception.

```
  powershell_script 'create file if no error' do
    code <<-EOH
      Write-Output 'File Created' | Out-File c:/users/vagrant/desktop/files.txt
    EOH
    not_if 'throw bad call'
  end
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What kind of error are you trying to check with `throw bad call`? We may not even need to use `powershell_script` with guard depending on the requirement.

Comment: The not_if ends up making a http call to OctopusDeploy and asking if a node exists. My network is kinda flaky, so I think that the node is unable to connect to octopus and therefore throws an error and ends up returning false.

I'm not 100% what happens next, but when that happens, I would just like execution to stop, so it doesn't accidently do something I don't want it to do.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290397/how-do-you-abort-end-a-chef-run) seems to be related. You can try using standard Ruby error handling in the form of `begin`/`rescue`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the answer doesn't show how to get it so that an exception will stop the run from the powershell_guard clause. That being said, I found a workaround which is similar to the logic prescribed in your article. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a good way to do this, so in order to make it work, I switched the call to be a ruby guard that's calling powershell_out as opposed to using the default powershell guard functionality.

```
  # This will stop the run because of the error thrown in the guard
  powershell_script 'create file if no error' do
    code <<-EOH
      Write-Output 'File Created' | Out-File c:/users/vagrant/desktop/files.txt
    EOH
    not_if { powershell_out!('throw bad call').stdout =~ /True/i }
  end
```

This is useful in a use case where you're making a call to get some information from the network and that network is temporarily unavailable during the call

```
  # If blah.exe throws an exception, the run will be stopped
  # else, it will perform the normal register logic if blah.exe returns a not "true"
  powershell_script 'do_something_if_not_registered' do
    code <<-EOH
      &blah.exe register
    EOH
    not_if { powershell_out!('&blah.exe isRegistered').stdout =~ /True/i }
  end
```

If anyone else finds/knows a better way to do this, please let me know.